# Linear Regression Machine Learning training the model with huge data

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am working on a Machine Learning Linear Regression problem where my train File is around 8GB.

Though my Tp is of high configuration, its not supporting. So Instead of passing the entire file for the training purpose, can I divide the train file into
10/20 files and train the model with these files one by one?

Will this approach work or do I have to train the model with the entire data in one shot?

Comment: Would you be able to provide more information? What have you tried? Why can't you run the 8gb file (which is relatively small for most machine learning)? What you using for your machine learning? This information will help us give better answers, thanks!

Comment: what kind of data are we talking, can you give a sample?  What are the specs of your machine and 8Gb is not a very small dataset but it's not even huge! Although running it in chunks is not a very big deal but first we need information!

Comment: Hi Steve, I am trying to predict the values of a amount to be paid using Linear Regression. Could you please suggest how to proceed. Please find the code below:

Comment: import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(data_path,index_col=0)

Comment: Hi Ubdus, Could you please help me on the process of running the code in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that works. It's called Stochastic Gradient Descent to do it that way, and is a standard way to train when your data cannot fit in memory.

Stochastic means "with randomness", and is called this because you're not following the actual gradient of all your data, but an approximation of your gradient based on some of your data. Even though you're not always updating in the exact right direction, as long as your step size is small enough and your batches are large enough, the procedure still works very well.

**But, a word of caution:** You can't train it to completion on each file, one after the other. If you do this, training on the second file will cause it to forget the values it learned on the first file.

Instead, you should be training it on what they call "batches" of data, and do one update-step per batch.

**So, this is bad:**

```
for file in files:
    while not Model.stop_condition():
        Model.train_step(file)
```

**And this is good:**

```
while not Model.stop_condition():
    for file in files:
        Model.train_step(file)
```

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks for the solution. It will be very helpful if you provide some code for reference especially for reading .csv files one after another and training the model.